# Python execution and sleep timing variance

Tags: python, timing

I'm running a script to gather data, and I'm noticing some weird variations in the timing.

I've got a script that polls for data off of the I2C via the FTDI library, and it pulls data in at 3.5 HZ. It's solid and works great. Here it is (let's call it `poll_data.py`):

```
while time.time() < start_time + duration_in_seconds:
    if not stop_queue.empty():
        if stop_queue.get():
            logger.debug('Break received, exiting collection after {0} seconds'.format(time.time() - start_time))
            break
    data = get_data()
    cache.append(",".join(str(x) for x in [time.time() - start_time] + data]))
    counter += 1
    if len(cache) == 50:
        write_to_log_file(file_id, cache)
        cache = []
```

The queue was added so this script can be run asynchronously and stopped via some outside timing.

After running some tests, I noticed that I get weird stop times. Say I have a simple test:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from poll_data import polling, stop_queue

start_time = time.time()
test_time = 60
duration = 80
process = Thread(target=polling, args=duration)
process.start()
interval = test_time - (time.time() - start_time)
time.sleep(interval)
stop = time.time()
stop_queue.put(True)
while process.is_alive():
    pass
end = time.time()
run_information.append((start_time, interval, stop - start_time, end - start_time))
```

After running this 105 times (in reality it's in a loop that runs x times, shortened here for ease of reading), I see some weird variations in execution times. Here's a small sample

```
                         Run information                             
     Start      |    Interval     |   Process End   |    Finished      
1402934605.5525 |         59.9994 |         61.5621 |         64.3632  
1402934670.9171 |         59.9991 |         60.5022 |         62.8066  
1402934734.7252 |         59.9995 |         71.3656 |         77.0946  
1402934812.8211 |         59.9996 |         61.4797 |         61.6411  
1402934875.4637 |         59.9995 |         60.7879 |         60.7954  
1402934937.2605 |         59.9995 |         60.2218 |         60.5099  
1402934998.7719 |         59.9995 |         62.2200 |         65.0900  
1402935064.8633 |         59.9994 |         60.0802 |         60.4974  
1402935126.3622 |         59.9994 |         61.5364 |         63.3869  
1402935190.7505 |         59.9995 |         61.5147 |         61.9220  



Average Interval 59.99951714    Max 59.9998     Min 59.9991
                 62.28667048        71.3757         60.0485
                 64.23963714        77.0946         60.2074
```

I'm curious why the sleep interval always seems to be the same, but the stop time is very different, and the finish time is as well. The process ends immediately after the item is put in the queue, but that seems to take a while?

What's going on here?

EDIT: Added `process.start()` in appropriate place.

Comment: What happens to the times if you use `process.join()` instead of the while loop?

Comment: Also, note that your end and finished times use the `start_time` which includes the time to create the thread. I'm guessing the times might become a little more stable if you set `start_time` after the thread was created. And when do you call `process.start()`?

Comment: Haven't tried process.join(), in production several processes are started, I just noticed this one had many different end times. (The others probably do as well, but they just output cumulative results, not several per second).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a satisfying answer, but I think it's just based on the operating system scheduling since the code you've shown doesn't look like it can cause any other delays. You have a couple important factors in play here. You are using the `sleep` function which itself says it may take less or more time depending:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

You are using threads which in Python are not run concurrently because of the GIL. And finally what was the computer running these tests doing while you ran them? Maybe the python process wasn't getting scheduled as often as it should. My comment before was a little wrong since the interval shows that the thread creation time is pretty constant. If you aren't showing all of the code involved it's possible there are other factors (ex. file reading/writing causing IO waits).

Maybe try a quick sanity check:

```
import time
start = time.time()
time.sleep(60)
stop = time.time()
print stop - start
```

**Edit**

And to bring up `join` again from my comment, if you use `join` then the main thread will be blocked on waiting for the thread and won't be running any actual code. This way any processing time can be given to the thread to catch the stop signal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think adding a time.sleep(0.001) to the polling loop has really helped tighten up the timing for some reason. I'll have to do some testing to see if it changes the number of data points collected in that time.